Why mbtiles file is so big?
I want to create very simple world map with coastline and countries. For this, I extracted country borders from planet OSM. PBF file is only 24MB.
Next, with tilemaker I created mbtiles file (with coastline), and the size is 24GB(!).
I think, the problem comes from coastline - it's very detailed.
How to simplify it ? I need very generic map...
